# php crawler for website with ajax content and https

Tags: php, ajax, curl, web-crawler

i'm trying to grab the content of a website based on ajax and https but with no luck.

Is this possible.

The website i'm trying to crawl is this:

https://www.bet3000.com/en/html/home.html#!https://www.bet3000.com/html/en/eventssportsbook.html?category_id=2117

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the HTTP requests that this page is doing *(using, for example, Firebug for Firefox)*, you'll notice it makes several Ajax requests.

Instead of trying to execute the Javascript code, a possible solution could be for you to request one of those URLs, and get the data -- you'd also not have to parse the HTML, this way.

In this specific case, one of those requests is made to the following URL :

```
https://www.bet3000.com/ajax/en/sportsbook.json.html?category_id=2117&offset=&live=&sportsbook_id=0
```

This URL seems to return some JSON data, that should interest you quite a bit ;-)

*(There is a few characters before and after the JSON, that will need to be removed, but, asides from that, I don't see anything that doesn't look good.)*

Comment: Hi again :) i tried to get the content of that url but with no success. I used curl and file_get_contents but i get empty values, but if i put that url in browser i get the results... How can i get that content?Thanks?

Comment: OK; done i made it... function file_get_contents_curl($url)
{
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 0);
 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 $res = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close ($ch);
 return $res; 
}